# How can I get ALL links posted by a user's Facebook friends in the last few days?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to get all links posted by a user and his/her Facebook friends.

I am using Facebook PHP SDK and have the following FQL so far:

```
$fql = "SELECT link_id, owner, owner_comment, created_time, title, summary, url, image_urls 
          FROM link WHERE owner IN 
            (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() LIMIT 100) 
          AND created_time >= $_7ago";
```

For some reason, the above FQL works only for certain friends but gives errors for others. Does this have to do with privacy issues of these friends?

Also, even when the query works, the process takes more than 10 seconds. Is there an alternative way to get what I am looking for?

***Thanks.***

Answer (score 1):

The not showing of data for certain friends is a Facebook privacy feature. If one of your friends has restricted their privacy settings so that a post (or all posts) aren't visible to everyone, their posts won't be returned by the API.

Some objects have a `visible` property that you can filter the results through. Link doesn't seem to be one of them.

For a query of this size, 10 sec could be in the range of what this will take. Most queries that I see that involve the `friend` table take at least 5 sec.